# Default SelectedValue in DropDownList changed after DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have DetailsView in InsertMode and within it i have Fields and some of these Fields are DropDownLists , these DropDownLists are take its items from database and i sit for each dropdownlist a defaultselectedvalue for example --Select one --
when i click on insert button in detailsview the selectedvalue in dropdownlists changed from the --Select one -- to the first item of datasource

my question is how to sit my default selected value again after dropdownlists Binding?

Comment: what you have tried already ?

Comment: is  --Select one -- there in dropdown after databind? can you show us the databind code?

Comment: i tried to take the last state that i want for each dropdownlist in sessions and calling them in the event "detailsview item inserted" but its not work